# Django form returning 'NaN' when receiving long numbers from a javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms, numbers

In a Django project I have a javascript that sends some coordinates of an image to a Django form. Then the users submit the form and after some logic is applied the coordinates are saved to database. Most of the time it works well but sometimes the javascript (which I have limited access to) sends this kind of numbers: 55.46353234234234e-14 and in the form data I get this kind of variables: u'middle_img_center_y': [u'NaN'] instead of the numbers I usually get. And then of course I get Value Errors of the kind : cannot convert float NaN to integer.
I don't know if I can catch that number and modify it to fit what the form is expecting or if I can set the form differently to accept these numbers (right now it is a forms.FloatField).
Thanks for your help.

some code:

the view:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = ImageForm()
else:
    form = ImageForm(request.POST)
    ... doing some cropping here then save
```

the form:

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Image

top_img_left = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
... then more of the same line but with middle, bottom, center, right...
```

This comes as a string.

The js code:

```
var topZoomData = $('#img-top-remix').smoothZoom('getZoomData');
$('input[name="top_img_left"]').val(topZoomData.scaledX);
```

Update:

I'm trying now with the toFixed function to avoid such large numbers:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

```
var topZoomData = $('#img-top-remix').smoothZoom('getZoomData');
$('input[name="top_img_left"]').val(topZoomData.scaledX).toFixed(3);
```

Comment: Show the code you used to post form data...Are you sending this as a string?

Comment: The code is quite simple, I'll update it in the question

Comment: the value of the number 55.46353234234234e-14 is generated by javascript or python

Comment: I asked you to post the JS code....

Comment: @viveksoundrapandi I could not make that clear in your first comment, if possible I'd prefer an answer on the Django side of things, to avoid touching the JS. I updated the question with the javascript. Anyway I think the updated code I posted should do it (JS side, not Django). Tell me what you think.

Comment: @Bastian, vivek is asking for the JS code because JS is sending the value 'NaN' instead of a number. Your python error is trying to convert 'NaN' which is a string 'not a number', hence 'NaN'.